# Wendy's Spicy Chicken Sandwich

Tags: chicken, sandwich

What year was the [Wendy's Spicy Chicken Sandwich](https://www.wendys.com/en-us/chicken/spicy-chicken-sandwich) first made available for sale?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia's article on Wendy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy's#Notable_menu_items) says it was added to the menu full-time in 1996, and was a promotional thing before then. There's no source given, unfortunately, but I found [this 1996 shareholder report](http://library.corporate-ir.net/library/67/675/67548/items/307410/1996ar.pdf) saying "This year we added two permanent additions to the menu -- the innovative Spicy Chicken Sandwich...", and on youtube you can find [tons of copies of their ad](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wendy%27s%20spicy%20chicken%201996) marked as being from 1996.

I *think* it was first sold as a promotional thing in 1992, but I didn't find a really solid source yet. The best I've found is [this ad for the *new* spicy chicken sandwitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTWiNcPhVgM) marked as being from 1992.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Wendy's Story**](https://www.wendys.com/en-us/about-wendys/the-wendys-story) says it was in April 2004.

Comment: It says they launched "a crispier Spicy Chicken" in 2004. I don't think it says when the original one was first available.